# Flex : data binding to numeric stepper not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.6

I'm trying to get two way data binding to work with a numeric stepper.  It binds from value to display OK, but when I update the GUI the model value is not changed.  How can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
        [Bindable]
        private var val:Number = 2;

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:NumericStepper x="30" y="27" value="{val}"/>
<s:Button x="30" y="58" label="Apply" click="trace(val);"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get two-way binding, you need a different syntax:

```
<s:NumericStepper x="30" y="27" value="@{val}"/>
```

Notice the `@` sign before the opening brace. Otherwise, it is just one-way